# Every/other CSS techniques

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, event-handling

I am creating a page with 4 different sections. In each section there is a responsive image and on the image there is text and some buttons. Right now they are aligned a bit off center and to the right. I am trying to achieve so that the 1st div the text and buttons float right and the 2nd div the text and buttons float left and so on. I am using the even odd nth property but it is only responding on the even css nth property. Here is the CSS and html. Keep in mind I am just using the background color now as an example and will put in the floats and padding if I get it working.

```
    .popup-open:nth-child(odd) {
   background: #ff0000;
    }

    .popup-open:nth-child(even) {
    background: #000000;
    }

    <div class="popup-open">
            <div class="icons-large">

                                <?php 

                                $fields = CFS()->get('icons_large');

                                if($fields) :
                                    foreach ($fields as $field) : ?>
                                    <div class="row">
                                            <div class="image">
                                                <img src="<?php echo $field['icons_big'];?>" alt="">
                                            </div>
                                    </div>

                                <?php endforeach; endif; ?>

                            </div>
            <div class="icons-large">

                                <?php 

                                $fields = CFS()->get('tour_titles');

                                if($fields) :
                                    foreach ($fields as $field) : ?>

                                                <?php echo $field['tour_name'];?>

                                <?php endforeach; endif; ?>

                            </div>
            <div class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a class to the divs and target them that way, you will have more control over it too.

```
    if($fields) :
$i = 1;
  foreach ($fields as $field) :

if($i === 2){
 $class = "even";
 $i = 1;
}else if($i === 1){
    $class = "odd";
 $i = 2;
}
<div class="row <?=$class;?>">
<div class="image">
<img src="<?php echo $field['icons_big'];?>" alt="">

</div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

Comment: I am unclear on how this works within my code. I tried using it and totally just broke it.